# SQL Query Joins not working properly

Tags: mysql, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

For a project I needed to create a DB for a small Olympics. My ER Diagram is as shown... 
[image]
link to better picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYP32.png

I need to create a query that includes only competitors that are competing in more than one event (that's only two competitors) and to list the name, event, venue, and result.

The query below works as it should producing 70 (# of competitors) records with the count at 2 for competitors competing in two events...

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, COUNT(r.competitorid)
FROM  COMPETITOR c LEFT OUTER JOIN ( REGISTRATION r LEFT OUTER JOIN  EVENT e 
               ON r.eventid = e.eventid ) ON r.competitorid = c.competitorid
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname
ORDER BY c.firstname;
-----------------------------------------
NORRIS  HOLMWOOD    1
OCTAVIO MARTINEZ    1
ORFEO   SILVA       2
etc...
```

After including the event name in the query it produces 72 results with competitors competing in two events listed twice but the COUNT() is 1 for everything.

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, e.eventname, COUNT(r.competitorid)
FROM  COMPETITOR c LEFT OUTER JOIN ( REGISTRATION r LEFT OUTER JOIN  EVENT e 
ON r.eventid = e.eventid ) ON r.competitorid = c.competitorid
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname, e.eventname
ORDER BY c.firstname;
----------------------------------------------------------------
NORRIS  HOLMWOOD    100 METER BUTTERFLY 1
OCTAVIO MARTINEZ    FLOOR EXERCISE  1
ORFEO   SILVA   100 METER BUTTERFLY 1
ORFEO   SILVA   400 METER INDIV MEDLEY  1
PONCIO  ASIS    POMMEL HORSE    1
PONCIO  BARROS  LONG JUMP   1
```

Then this is were things really get messed up. When I join the result table with the event table, the output stays the same with 72 records but the count is completely wrong.

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, e.eventname, COUNT(r.competitorid)
FROM  COMPETITOR c LEFT OUTER JOIN ( REGISTRATION r LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    EVENT e right OUTER JOIN RESULT rs ON e.eventid = rs.eventid)
    ON r.eventid = e.eventid ) ON r.competitorid = c.competitorid
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname, e.eventname
ORDER BY c.firstname;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
NIKOLAI MIKHAILOV   POMMEL HORSE        6
NOEMI   PELAEZ  BALANCE BEAM            7
NORRIS  HOLMWOOD    100 METER BUTTERFLY 6
OCTAVIO MARTINEZ    FLOOR EXERCISE      6
ORFEO   SILVA   100 METER BUTTERFLY     6
ORFEO   SILVA   400 METER INDIV MEDLEY  6
PONCIO  ASIS    POMMEL HORSE            6
```

My question is what am I doing wrong? The joins seem to be working at least partly how I want them to, the problem is with the messed up count(). It doesn't necessarily matter the numbers are bigger, the problem is the count seems to be fairly random for some reason.

Comment: Picture is very blurry

Comment: @phil652 click on the image and zoom in. It's very clear.

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed by the types of joins.  You want all competitors and all results?  Why is the right join in there?  You can't have results without a registration and event right?  So shouldn't it be a left join? `FROM  COMPETITOR c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN REGISTRATION r 
  ON r.competitorid = c.competitorid
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENT e 
  ON r.eventid = e.eventid  
LEFT OUTER JOIN RESULT rs 
  ON e.eventid = rs.eventid  and c.CompetitorID = Rs.CompetitorID
` and ()'s just make it harder to read IMO...  and ***you appear to be missing a join on Competitor to results***.

Comment: @xQbert Yeah, the ()'s do make it harder to read, its just how I've seen multiple JOIN ON's used. I did not know they were not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider: (A result is **also** specific to a competitor so you missed that join criteria.)
Also, Right join means you want all records from results and all records as other tables are LEFT joining to Competitor. Since a result logically is based on competitor, I'm guessing the right join is incorrect.

So two fold issue on counts  1 the missing join criteria was causing counts to inflate, and the right join **may** have also caused problems but since a result is dependent on a competitor, you may not see any issues.

If you want the number of events a competitor is registered, you need to derive that count [desperately spelling error was too funny to take out] separately and then join back in (there are other ways but I generally prefer this method as it seems to be DB agnostic)

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, e.eventname, CE.TotalNumberOFEvents
FROM  COMPETITOR c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN REGISTRATION r 
  ON r.competitorid = c.competitorid
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENT e 
  ON r.eventid = e.eventid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RESULT rs    --Not sure why this is a right join... on your qry.
  ON e.eventid = rs.eventid
 AND Rs.CompetitorID = C.CompetitorID  ---ADDED this and removed the ()'s putting join critier under the joins. 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(RegistrationID) as TotalNumberOfEvents, CompetitorID 
           FROM Registration) as CE    --added this to get the # of events a competitor is in (independant of the event name listed)
  ON Ce.CompetitorID = C.CompetitorID
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname, e.eventname
ORDER BY c.firstname;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This definitely solves the problem with the random count()s, they are all now 1, I completely missed that last join. 

All the competitors are displayed along with duplicates if they are in more than one event (72 records), but how would I discern the competitors competing in multiple events since the counts are all 1?

Comment: you need to join to a subquery where the counts are derived prior to joins  example in updated version.

Comment: Okay, so the the subquery is joined last to essentially get the correct count    from the original registration table, because after the registration table is joined the count won't display what I want it to? Am I understanding the logic behind this correctly? It displays exactly what I need for the WHERE condition BTW, you are a life saver!!!!!

Comment: more or less you have it.  The reason we have to get the counts in a separate query has to do with what you have to group by.  Since each event per competitor would always result in 1 and only 1 record, we need to get the counts without showing the events a competitor is tied to.  I used left join but an inner join after competitor would work as well.  order in the query doesn't really matter (in this case).  I am making a logical assumption that a result can't occur without a competitor, an event and a registration.  If a competitor can have a result without registration my approach is flawed

Comment: but as event is part of the key for Result, I think I'm safe.  Now in other RDBMS systems, you could use a window function such as `count() over Partition by (CompetitorID) as TotalNumberofEvents` which could do this without the subquery, but mySQL doesn't support such syntax.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I think I will be able to complete the other queries using this. Thanks again! And you are correct, a result cannot occur without a competitor, registration, and event.